# Unable to boot to ubuntu - no GRUB at startup

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, uefi

Recently I had some errors on my efi boot partition which caused me to delete it and create a new one. Since then I'm unable to boot to ubuntu - system boots straight to Windows 10 even though I used boot repair from live usb to restore grub. Even when I insert ubuntu live usb, I don't see a menu from which I can select either to try ubuntu or install it - it goes straight to try ubuntu.

I've already checked that I'm booting in UEFI mode and secure check is disabled. My hdd boots in UEFI boot mode as well.

When I tried to reinstall ubuntu, the installer couldn't find efi partition which resulted in failure.

Partitions:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: ST1000LM024 HN-M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 670699A6-5183-4F2E-BC80-89DCB9776337

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047   2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2582528    4630527   2048000  1000M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda3     4630528    4892671    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4     4892672  532027828 527135157 251.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5   532029440 1016504319 484474880   231G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  1016504320 1018341375   1837056   897M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1018341376 1019369471   1028096   502M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8  1019369472 1020291071    921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda9  1020291072 1663533055 643241984 306.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda10 1663533056 1675251711  11718656   5.6G Linux swap
/dev/sda11 1675251712 1675661311    409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda12 1911580672 1953523711  41943040    20G Windows recovery environment




Disk /dev/sdb: 14.7 GiB, 15728640000 bytes, 30720000 sectors
Disk model: ProductCode     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 75B7A4EB-E75E-4E5D-9734-D9F461F17F7F

Device     Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 30719966 30717919 14.7G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 35.3 MiB, 37027840 bytes, 72320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I'd be really grateful for help. I'd be also glad to provide more information if you need it.

Comment: You need to UEFI and its requirements, namely the EFI partition must be at the beginning of the drive.

Comment: You need to **know** UEFI and it's requirements... ^^^

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you mean I have to somehow restore efi partition on /dev/sda2?

Comment: It should be at the beginning of the drive. Not necessarily the first one but must be within I think the first 2GB, yours is at the end of the drive.

Comment: According to https://askubuntu.com/questions/618244/does-the-uefi-partition-either-must-or-should-be-first-for-some-reason-if-s anwser, efi partition should be at the first 2TB of the drive

Comment: Have you tried using manual partitioning during installation, or are you using guided partitioning. Guided partitioning isn’t really all that great at detecting partitions that are newly created; usually it defaults to creating its own ESP, which could be the problem. Delete your Ubuntu partition, and mount your ESP and delete all the GRUB files (usually in a folder called \EFI\ubuntu and reinstall using manual partitioning and specifying the ESP (that’s key to manual partitioning; usually the EFI partition is detected but sometimes it isn’t)

Comment: Thank for answer. I used this https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows to reinstall grub manually, however with no success.